# Decode in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way to decode the below string,

```
"location.replace(i+\"&utm_content=\"+s)}(document,window,navigator,screen,\"\\x68\\x74\\x74\\x70\\x3a\\x2f\\x2f\\x6d\\x6f\\x62\\x76\\x69\\x64\\x69\\x2e\\x6d\\x6f\\x62\\x73\\x74\\x61\\x72\\x72\\x2e\\x63\\x6f\\x6d\\x2f\\x3f\\x75\\x74\\x6d\\x5f\\x74\\x65\\x72\\x6d\\x3d\\x36\\x35\\x34\\x33\\x34\\x39\\x39\\x37\\x36\\x39\\x31\\x38\\x32\\x39\\x34\\x36\\x33\\x30\\x32\\x26\\x63\\x6c\\x69\\x63\\x6b\\x76\\x65\\x72\\x69\\x66\\x79\\x3d\\x31\",fi
```

I have tried as,

```
URI.unescape string
```

But its not working

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: `[s.gsub("\\x","")].pack("H*") #=> "http://mobvidi.mobstarr.com/?utm_term=6543499769182946302&clickverify=1"` where s is the hex string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be another way to do this, but here's one way:

```
>> hex = "\\x68\\x74\\x74\\x70\\x3a\\x2f\\x2f\\x6d\\x6f\\x62\\x76\\x69\\x64\\x69\\x2e\\x6d\\x6f\\x62\\x73\\x74\\x61\\x72\\x72\\x2e\\x63\\x6f\\x6d\\x2f\\x3f\\x75\\x74\\x6d\\x5f\\x74\\x65\\x72\\x6d\\x3d\\x36\\x35\\x34\\x33\\x34\\x39\\x39\\x37\\x36\\x39\\x31\\x38\\x32\\x39\\x34\\x36\\x33\\x30\\x32\\x26\\x63\\x6c\\x69\\x63\\x6b\\x76\\x65\\x72\\x69\\x66\\x79\\x3d\\x31"
=> "\\x68\\x74\\x74\\x70\\x3a\\x2f\\x2f\\x6d\\x6f\\x62\\x76\\x69\\x64\\x69\\x2e\\x6d\\x6f\\x62\\x73\\x74\\x61\\x72\\x72\\x2e\\x63\\x6f\\x6d\\x2f\\x3f\\x75\\x74\\x6d\\x5f\\x74\\x65\\x72\\x6d\\x3d\\x36\\x35\\x34\\x33\\x34\\x39\\x39\\x37\\x36\\x39\\x31\\x38\\x32\\x39\\x34\\x36\\x33\\x30\\x32\\x26\\x63\\x6c\\x69\\x63\\x6b\\x76\\x65\\x72\\x69\\x66\\x79\\x3d\\x31"
>> Array(hex.gsub("\\x","")).pack('H*')
=> "http://mobvidi.mobstarr.com/?utm_term=6543499769182946302&clickverify=1"
```

I created a string variable for the hex string and then stripped out the backslashes and 'x' characters. Then, this is converted into an array so we can call the `pack` method (specifying the capital `H` string directive for a high nibble first hex string) which you can read about [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/pack).